# Why does IntelliJ Structural Search find some of `(int) ($expr$ + 0.5f)`, but not all?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, structural-search

I'm trying to use Structural Search to replace a rounding anti-pattern with the correct pattern. I'm searching for:

```java
(int) ($expr$ + 0.5f)
```

in order to replace it with:

```java
Math.round($expr$)
```

Strangely, that search pattern finds *most* of the instances of the anti-pattern, but not all, and I can't see any relevant difference. Here are two it **doesn't** find:

```java
return (int) (lowestHeight / 256f + minHeight + 0.5f);
```

and

```java
return (int) ((lowestHeight & 0xFFFF) / 256f + minHeight + 0.5f);
```

But just a few lines above, it had no problem with this expression:

```java
return (int) (getHeight(x, y) + 0.5f);
```

or a few lines below with this expression:

```java
if (((tallWaterLevel[xx + yy * TILE_SIZE]) > ((int) (tallHeightMap[xx + yy * TILE_SIZE] / 256f + 0.5f)))
```

nor with dozens of other similar instances in the codebase. I don't see the difference.

What's going on? Why doesn't it find the first two expressions? What's the difference, and how do I make it find them?

I've already [asked this question on the Jetbrains Community site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5000866357906-Why-does-Structural-Search-find-some-of-int-expr-0-5f-but-not-all-), and I got a response that seems to be implying it is a bug. I am hoping to get more views here and that it yet might turn out it is based on a lack of understanding on my part.

I have not set any filters or changed any Structural Search settings from the default. As I said, it actually finds *most* instances of the pattern.

Comment: "I've already asked this question on the Jetbrains Community site" can you provide a link?

Comment: @AndyTurner I've added a link,

Answer (score 1):

I am going to surmise - I have no concrete evidence for this - but there could be some issue with the way intellij handles associativity of the `+` operator - it should be left associative, but perhaps it is considering it right associative, so it reads your expression

```
lowestHeight / 256f + minHeight + 0.5f
```

as

```
lowestHeight / 256f + (minHeight + 0.5f)  // right associative, doesn't match
```

rather than

```
(lowestHeight / 256f + minHeight) + 0.5f  // left associative, does match
```

I don't have a clever workaround for this: all I can suggest is to try searching for:

```
(int) ($expr1$ + $expr2$ + 0.5f)
```

Comment: Intriguing. It feels like associativitiy should not enter into it, but perhaps it is trying to be too clever for its own good. I'll investigate that possibility.